# How can I find the number of unused GCE CPUs on my google cloud account?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

If I have GCE instances running and I want to launch another from app engine, how can I automatically determine if I have enough CPUs for the machine type I want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do this programmatically, you need to pull 'region' resources [see below] that have
information about your project regional vCPU quotas and current usage
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/regions

You can also use gcloud tool to get this info:

gcloud compute regions list --project YOUR_PROJECT

$ gcloud compute regions list

NAME         CPUS          DISKS_GB    ADDRESSES RESERVED_ADDRESSES STATUS TURNDOWN_DATE

asia-east1      **0.00/24.00**      0/5120      0/23      0/7           UP

europe-west1    **0.00/24.00**      0/5120      0/23      0/7           UP

us-central1     **4.00/24.00**     30/5120      3/23      1/7           UP

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to having enough CPU quota available to spin up machines of a certain type?  if so, you can see your quota allotment at this link: https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/compute/quotas

Comment: I want to be able to get this value in code or, more specifically, this value minus the CPUs I'm currently using

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/projects. Looks like you can get quota by project with gcloud "describe" command, but not unused quota.